# Amazon SES SendTemplatedEmail with Tags defined using Tags.member.N

Tags: arrays, json, email, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a templated email using Amazon SES and an API call using the following code.

```
Action:SendTemplatedEmail
Source: sourceemail@email.com
Destination.ToAddresses.member.1: destemail@email.com 
Template: template_name
TemplateData:{"firstname":"Name"}
Tags.member.1:{"tag1name":"tag1value","tag2name":"tag2value"}
```

This is all working fine except the last line where im trying to add tags. After adding the last line I receive the error below.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
    <Message>Unexpected complex element termination</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>e00f3de2-57ef-4f20-b427-959c1f1a974d</RequestId>
```

I think I am just not formatting the array correctly? But I have tried every combination I can think of with no luck. Any ideas?

I have also tried using

```
Action:SendTemplatedEmail
Source: sourceemail@email.com
Destination.ToAddresses.member.1: destemail@email.com 
Template: template_name
TemplateData:{"firstname":"Name"}
Tags.member.N:["tag1name":"tag1value","tag2name":"tag2value"]
```

Which gives a slightly more useful error as below.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>2 validation errors detected: Value null at 'tags.1.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'tags.1.member.value' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>e6c3bc02-d7ab-40b6-8389-7a041fdb84ce</RequestId>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the structure has to look like this:

```
Tags: [
    {
      Name: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      Value: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
    },
    /* more items */
  ]
```

Comment: No luck unfortuantelty. Tried all the options below

Name: 'STRING_VALUE',Value: 'STRING_VALUE'
{Name: 'STRING_VALUE',Value: 'STRING_VALUE'}
[{Name: 'STRING_VALUE',Value: 'STRING_VALUE'}]

Answer (score 0):

Seems Message tags only applies to SendEmail and SendRawEmail API operations with Event publishing:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_MessageTag.html